# Selenium for driver.find_element_by_name() for Internet Explorer

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I am training to fill forms automatically in Internet Explorer. I did the following code for Chrome and I succeeded but the same code fails for Internet Explorer. My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import IEDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path="C:/Program Files (x86)/IEDriverServer.exe", capabilities={'ignoreZoomSetting':True})

driver.get("https://rosamorel.com/ebook-copywriting-textos-persuasivos/")
nombre = "example"
email = "example@gmail.com"
accionar = driver.find_element_by_name("input_1.3")
accionar.send_keys(nombre)
accionar = driver.find_element_by_name("input_2")
accionar.send_keys(email)
accionar = driver.find_element_by_name("input_5.1")
accionar.click()
```

IE opens, it gets the website I want but it stops there with the next error in the Console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Abel\Documents\Ejercicios_python\web_scrapin_test copy.py", line 11, in <module>
    accionar = driver.find_element_by_name("input_1.3")
  File "C:\Users\Abel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 496, in find_element_by_name     
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Users\Abel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\Abel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Abel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response        
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find element with name == input_1.3
```

I tried .find_element_by_id and I have the same problem. I do not why because this method works perfectly for Chrome ¡.
Could anyone help?

Comment: Why are you using Internet explorer ? The support has been discontinued, Is there any specific reason ?

Comment: Because my copmany uses a software solution integrated in Internet Explorer. It works in Edge as well but you cannot even see the code, so I want to try in IE. I wish I could do it in Chrome haha

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a wait / delay before accessing these elements.
Please try this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import IEDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path="C:/Program Files (x86)/IEDriverServer.exe", capabilities={'ignoreZoomSetting':True})
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get("https://rosamorel.com/ebook-copywriting-textos-persuasivos/")
nombre = "example"
email = "example@gmail.com"
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "input_1.3"))).send_keys(nombre)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "input_2"))).send_keys(email)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "input_5.1"))).click()
```

In case `By.NAME` will not work try By.CSS_SELECTOR as following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import IEDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path="C:/Program Files (x86)/IEDriverServer.exe", capabilities={'ignoreZoomSetting':True})
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get("https://rosamorel.com/ebook-copywriting-textos-persuasivos/")
nombre = "example"
email = "example@gmail.com"
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='input_1.3']"))).send_keys(nombre)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='input_2']"))).send_keys(email)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='input_5.1']"))).click()
```

Comment: In both cases I get this error:
"selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: Unable to find element on closed window"
Thanks your trying anyway =)

Comment: from you code I see no reason to window to close